# pig unable create sample number file in vim

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

This is most dumb question but anyways , i am just doing a testing and also learning apache pig . In process when ever I create sample data like (1,2,3) using **sudo vim** i**n ubuntu** . When I hit the grunt and run the local pig mode . 
for some reason when I try to dump the variable , it is empty .

```
data 
(1,2,3)



A = load 'data' as (f1:int)
Dump A

result 
()
```

But when i use chararray , i can see the result .
whats the problem . should i have to create the sample data using in different editor like cat . any idea

```
A = load 'data' as (F1:chararray)
Dump A
result 
(1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your input data format. If you want three columns with an integer, the file contents should look like this:

```
1,2,3
```

Notice the absence of braces. Pig adds the braces to make clear that it is a tuple. The reason why it works when using chararray is that it interprets `(1,2,3)` as a string (which on the other hand cannot be converted into an integer)

Loading would then be done like this:

```
A = load 'data' as (c1:int, c2:int, c3:int);
```